# Filter nested numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Hi I'm trying to filter the following numpy array but running into issues. I'd like to filter for all arrays equal to [('a','b','c'),1]. The problem is I can't figure out how to either combine the elements in each array so instead of [('a','b','c'),1], I would have [('a','b','c',1)], OR simply filter given the original structure. I tried a combination of np.concatenate() and np.ravel() but result wasn't expected.

```
a = np.array([[('a','b','c'), 1], [('b','c','a'), 1], [('a','b','c'), 2], [('a','b','c'), 1]])

Method:
Filter if 1st element = 'a', 2nd element = 'b', 3rd element ='c' and 4th element = 1

Desired Output:
output = np.array([[('a','b','c'), 1], [('a','b','c'), 1]])
```

EDIT: I was able to get this to work with a pandas solution, but only by converting it to a dataframe, which is too expensive thus why I'm trying to acheive a more optimized solution with numpy

Comment: In the latest `numpy` version your `a` expression produces a `ValueError`.  It requires an `dtype=object` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
a[(a == [('a', 'b', 'c'), 1]).all(1)]
```

Output:

```
array([[('a', 'b', 'c'), 1],
       [('a', 'b', 'c'), 1]], dtype=object)
```

Output of `a == [('a', 'b', 'c'), 1]` :

```
array([[ True,  True],
       [False,  True],
       [ True, False],
       [ True,  True]])
```

***Different comparators for different elements:***

N.B. You said 4th element in your comment, but its not really 4th element its second element with the way you constructed your numpy array.

Now if you are looking to have a condition like <= for the second element (integers) and == for the tuple elements (like ('a', 'b', 'c') ) there is no easy way in short because of the way array is constructed.

But a work around is to create an auxiliary array like:

```
abc = np.array([[('a','b','c'), 0]], dtype='O').repeat(len(a), axis=0)
```

and then use it to filter with different comparator for different columns like:

```
a[(a[:, 0] == abc[:, 0]) & (a[:, 1] <= 2)]
```

Comment: if I wanted to add a condition... lets say "element 4 <= 2", can this easily be modified to incorporate this logic?

Comment: element 4 where? in each row? can you add more concrete example?

Comment: yes element 4 in each row ie. the integer value so the output would also include the array [('a','b','c'), 2] in that case

Comment: @chicagobeast12 I updated answer to address your comment.

Answer (score 1):

In your case a more faster way is to compare 1st and 2nd item explicitly:

```
[r for r in a if r[0] == ('a','b','c') and r[1] == 1]
```

---

```
In [400]: %timeit [r for r in a if r[0] == ('a','b','c') and r[1] == 1]
1.2 µs ± 6.69 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [402]: %timeit a[(a == [('a', 'b', 'c'), 1]).all(1)]
7.21 µs ± 85.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: This is not vectorized though.

Comment: @SomeDude, [402] is "vectorized" - and slower.   I expect the [402] will scale better, but the arrays may have to be substantially larger.

Comment: ^ This. It is silly to show timing comparisons for an array of size 4 and claim your non-vectorized method is faster. The benefits of vectorization usually only show up for larger inputs. Scale it up, e.g. `a = np.array([[('a','b','c'), 1], [('b','c','a'), 1], [('a','b','c'), 2], [('a','b','c'), 1]] + [[tuple(random.sample("abcdefg", 3)), random.randint(1, 10)] for _ in range(10000)], dtype=object)`, and the vectorized approach is 2x faster

Comment: @hpaulj yes if the arrays are much bigger the vectorized approach will perform much better, timing on smaller arrays is not right comparison.

Comment: [400] would be faster `a` was a (nested) list